# Compute one point from detected shape in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, detection

i have to detect a point from an image. So far i thresholded the image and detected my interesting feature.

[image]

[image]

From this kind of feature i would like to have only one point,for example the center of the circle. I tried with HoughCircles (and then i would compute the center of the circle) but it does not detect anything, probably because they are not perfect circles.
Any help? Thanks

Comment: use findContours. then for each contour compute the `center of gravity` by averaging the contour point positions.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31281471/5008845) you can find an implementation using moments. Post the code you tried and the issues you're having, and we'll (try to) make it work